# Is it possible to launch the taskpane if certain conditions are met?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I want the user to press on a command button which will run an API. If the API returns results, I want this to launch the taskpane and then display the result of the API.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If we speak about web add-ins the task pane is launched by the button click independently of API results. At runtime you may decided what to display on the task pane.

But if you mean a custom task pane as a part of COM add-in you can do whatever you like - hide, show and etc.

Comment: This is a web add-in. I only want the taskpane to be launched if certain conditions are met by the API results. This button would execute a javascript function (but its main job would not be to launch the taskpane).

Comment: There is no API for launching a task pane from JS. You can specify to launch a task pane for your ribbon button and display any progress on the pane if the API call is made.

Answer (score 0):

For web add-ins, launching a task pane after running some code/API is not possible today.  We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Here are two alternatives I would suggest considering to see if they can work for your scenario

1. adding a command with ExecuteFunction as an action https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/functionfile and launching a dialog (displayDialogAsync)
2. Or, run ExecuteFunction that adds notification message with an action link that user can click to open a taskpane https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessageaction?view=outlook-js-preview