# Contextual Addin launched by variable regex

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'd like to know whether it is possible for a contextual addin to launch based on a variable  regex. An example would be that someone receives an email from john@microsoft.com. I want the regex to recognize the company name from the email address, and then use that as a rule to activate a contextual addin. So if in the email there was any mention of "microsoft", the word would be underlined.

I want to avoid having a huge regex that contains many different words, and instead build a regex that is dynamic.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have a other scenario in mind beyond just looking for company name? The regex definition is static in the manifest. I notice you also posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67991555/is-it-possible-to-launch-the-taskpane-if-certain-conditions-are-met and want to see if there's a bigger picture that may help us offer better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is defined in the manifest file, so I presume it can't be dynamically configurable. You can read more about that in the [Use regular expression activation rules to show an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-regular-expressions-to-show-an-outlook-add-in) article.

You can also find a sample web add-in at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-In-Contextual-Regex which shows how to use regex for activation rules.